# generating a pdf with dynamic google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to get mPDF to generate my report that has a lot of google charts on it. However it just ignores the charts and prints out black spaces.
Really dont know how to get the charts into the PDF.

Appreciate any help here please!

Thanks

Comment: you need to wait for each chart's `'ready'` event, before generating the pdf...

Comment: ok thanks! Will try get that happening